# JavaScript / XSS cookie stealing

Tags: javascript

If someone will clone my website login page will be able to steal the cookies of users if lets say will start a phishing campaign?

Comment: ... but maybe some credentials and other information the users enter.

Answer (score 0):

No. Cookies are scoped by domain name. For example, if you visit stackoverflow.com, your browser says, "oh, here's a cookie with domain=stackoverflow.com . I'll send that". But it wouldn't send your stackoverflow.com cookie to storkovalflaw.biz

However, the phishing website might convince some users to submit their usernames+passwords that they normally use on your site, which is bad.

You can sue someone for stealing your content and violating your copyright. You can submit phishing sites to [a variety of places](https://www.google.ca/webhp?#safe=off&q=submit%20phishing%20site).

Answer (score 0):

Phishing sites can't steal your cookies for reasons Neil gave, but cross-site scripting could theoretically. If you don't use the cookie in your site, it's generally best practice to set the cookie as http only, so it will be present on web requests but not accessible to javascript.

Pretty good writeup here:
http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/how-to-create-totally-secure-cookies

Comment: However if i clone my login page i am able to view some of them. I made the experiment.

Comment: What do you mean by clone your login page?  If you are running both on the same domain, you will be able to access cookies.

Comment: Content:              f210879d94504fa69dbb55680b2fb610
Content raw:          f210879d94504fa69dbb55680b2fb610
Expires:              Sunday, June 7, 2020 7:33:13 PM
Send for:             Encrypted connections only
Send for raw:         true
Created:              Tuesday, June 9, 2015 7:33:14 PM
HTTP only:            Yes
HTTP only raw:        true
This domain only:     No
This domain only raw: false

Comment: I'd never say never but it should be as safe as can be. :)  That cookie should be inaccessible to scripts and only sent on HTTPS connections to your domain (and subdomains).  Most sites would store basic credentialed information in a cookie like that.  Keep in mind good security practices still dictate keep as little information as you need there, because anyone with physical access to the machine can see it, and new vulnerabilities are found constantly.  This is true for anything though, not just cookies.